# "Comments are a code smell"

Tags: comments, anti-patterns

A coworker of mine believes that *any* use of in-code comments (ie, not javadoc style method or class comments) is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  What do you think?

Comment: I'm going to upvote any answer that says "no".

Comment: @Renesis That's the smell of divinity.

Comment: Your coworker made a sweeping generalization, which **automatically** means he is wrong. :)

Comment: In a perfect world or in a typical real software project?

Comment: @Thorbjørn - the examples are simplified but the principles still apply. Comments should be a last resort when all other refactoring has failed.

Comment: @Mongus, I disagree. The comments in your example is bad not because they are comments, but because they are TOO close to the code which then changes.  They should say _WHY_ and not _WHAT_.

Comment: @Alex, isn't that a sweeping generalization, which is therefore wrong (resulting in him not being wrong anyway)?

Comment: Comments are not code. Therefore no.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen yes, that was the point of the joke. Sweeping generalizations are pretty much always a sign that the speaker isn't thinking.

Comment: The whole point of "code smells" is that they're sweeping generalizations that aren't always right. They just tell you what to look at.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Only if the comment describes what the code is doing.

If I wanted to know what was happening in a method or block, I would read the code. I would hope, anyway, that any developers working on a given project were at least familiar enough with the development language to read what is written and understand what it is doing.

In some cases of extreme optimization, you might be using techniques that makes it difficult for someone to follow what your code is doing. In these cases, comments can and should be used to not only explain why you have such optimizations, but what the code is doing. A good rule of thumb would be to have someone else (or multiple other people) familiar with the implementation language and project look at your code - if they can't understand both the why and the how, then you should comment both the why and the how.

However, what's not clear in the code is why you have done something. If you take an approach that might not be obvious to others, you should have a comment that explains why you made the decisions that you did. I would suspect that you might not even realize that a comment is needed until after something like a code review, where people want to know why you did X instead of Y - you can capture your answer in the code for everyone else who looks at it in the future.

The most important thing, though, is to change your comments when you change your code. If you change an algorithm, be sure to update the comments with why you went with algorithm X over Y. Stale comments are an even bigger code smell.

Comment: I agree with this answer vis a vis comments, but I've also seen it cited as an excuse for lack of documentation, which is wrong. Reading code is a pain in the ass sometimes. You shouldn't *have* to look at the code for a method to figure out what that method does. You should be able to figure it out from the name and get some more details from the docs. When reading code, you often have to switch from class to class, and file to file. This especially a problem in dynamic languages, where writing an IDE that can handle all this is non-trivial.

Comment: Anyway, sometimes you have also to comment the HOW if it´s complicated (specially if it's optimized or any other kind of non-trivial operations). If I have to spend more than 5 minutes reading one block of code to understand what it's doing, can be pretty frustrating...

Comment: "Only if the comment describes what the code is doing." Or if the comment describes what the code used to do; the code has changed but the comment hasn't.

Comment: How do you test that your comment is correct? Why not write your comment as a test? Any future maintainer can use the test as the verifiable documentation for the code. If the comment has something to do with the execution of the code, then that something /must/ be assertable. If the comment has nothing to do with the execution of the code, then what is it doing in the code where only programmers will look?

Comment: @flamingpenguin - Even if you know what the code is doing, you still need to know why the code is doing it. Having to cross-reference the source code with the appropriate test case can be quite time consuming so why not just have "This code implements process X?" Of course, at that point you need to double check to make sure the comment is referring to the correct process in which case it might be wrong if someone doesn't maintain the comments.

Comment: @flamingpenguin: how do you write a unit test to explain that benchmarks showed using zip with a factor compression of 3 was sufficient but that if we were to increase the payload it might be worth augmenting it ? Or that using the Double-Metaphone algorithm was okay at the moment but would not work were we to have Indian clients ? I personally use a comment...

Comment: @Matthieu M - those are rare considerations. I do try to write tests that show that the code works or doesn't in as many cases as I can. I will go to the trouble of asserting the boundary conditions if they are likely enough. I do write comments in code, but they are extremely rare and only when I fail to find a better, verifiable, way of documenting the design decisions (as you say, for example when I absolutely cannot find a way of making an assertion about a performance characteristic for example). I see a lot more lazy comments as a substitute for a proper test than the other way around.

Comment: @flamingpenguin: I agree, I see a lot of useless / crappy / lazy comments too, but I prefer to avoid off-handed statements such as "never comment" :)

Comment: @Matthieu M - yeah, by itself "never comment" is no use. Maybe something like "prefer tests to comments" and "prefer readable code to comments"

Comment: @Rob Z - I put the "why" in my domain model method and class names. I put what the code is doing in the implementation. So I wouldn't write a method called addSeveralNumbers(). I would write getTotalInvoiceValue() in a class called "ProcessXInvoice"

Comment: @flamingpenguin: I like the two sentences you crafted :)

Comment: @flamingpenguin - Clear method and class names are good, but as others have noted, they don't guard against those edge cases where a comment is the fasted way of guarding against another developer changing something in the code that should not be changed. At the end of the day, so far in my career had a combination of clear variable, method, and class names along with appropriate comments where needed explaining why something was happening and where more information could be found.

Comment: @Rob Z - I am not sure we should be looking for the fastest way to do something. I agree that comments are fast. But I also think they are inherently unsafe. For example, they easily get detached from the related code during refactoring (e.g. extract method) with no automated way of detecting that human error. Even if the next developer reads the comment, they will not definitely understand it. Even if they do and try not to break it, they still accidentally might. A good test, although not as fast to write, does not have these flaws. It might not always be possible, but it almost always is.

Comment: @flamingpenguin - Maybe the fastest way of doing things is a poor way of describing things, but there is something to be said for having information at hand when you need it as opposed to having to look it up in a different part of the system. Having a test case to make sure the interest payment is calculated correctly is good, but having a comment in code saying something like `/* Don't truncate the fractional cents until after trade has cleared */` is also useful to developers.

Comment: @Rob Z - For "Don't truncate the fractional cents until after trade has cleared" I would create a type to enforces this rule. It could have a method truncatedValueForAfterTheTradeHasCleared() and it could encapsulate the operations to prevent the values from being truncated. I would also write tests to assert this. This way I could know without having to read all the code whether or not the rule "Don't truncate the fractional cents until after trade has cleared" was actually being followed, or if someone had made a mistake. I could reuse this rule as much as I like, without duplicate comments.

Comment: @back2dos, if you frequently vomit when reading other peoples code, I'm glad we are not sharing offices...

Comment: @CarsonMyers Prove it.

Answer (score 110):

This is particularly irritating to hear at the moment, I spent some time this weekend looking at very well-named, very clean, uncommented code implementing a research algorithm (one that isn't actually published). I'm high-level familiar with it, the guy sitting next to me was the inventor, and the code was written a few years ago by someone else. We could *barely* follow it.

Your co-worker is not experienced enough, obviously.

Comment: I'm curious to look at "well-named, very clean, uncommented code" that is hard to follow. Any code that I would classify as such has been very easy to follow. I certainly wouldn't go as far as "Your co-worker is not experienced enough, obviously".

Comment: @Liggy: I would. It's a research algorithm, not a line-of-business application.

Comment: I once had a piece of code where you had to populate fields in a database column object (3rd party) in the "wrong" order (defined by the "logic" of the process and our coding standards) - do it in the order we'd normally use and it would crash. No amount of reading the code could tell you this so it positively, absolutely, had to have a comment - and it wasn't a smell, at least not in code over which we had control (which is the bottom line). A complete and utter lack of comments is as much a smell as poor comments.

Comment: Math, math, math. Not all code implements trivial IoC glue and 'price * quantity'. Complex math cannot be made magically to self-explain.

Comment: @Liggy, code implementing complex datastructures can be completely incomprehensible without extensive documentation.

Comment: @Murph, nasty, can you remember why this was so?

Comment: @Thorbjørn it was an Oracle COM object being called from VB5/6 no idea why at all (other than it was, fairly obviously, a nasty and obscure bug) and it was over 10 years ago... but it illustrates the point. Similar issues now would be with things like formatting requests to web services where, for example, you have to populate redundant/optional fields despite logic and the manual (if any) telling you otherwise.

Comment: This answer reminds me of being in university days discussing Dijkstra's algorithm.  In the book, the pseudo-algorithm is a handful of lines but if you actually try to implement it you realize what the pseudo-code represents.  Its pretty, elegant, short and concise but far from straight-forward to implement.

Comment: @Paul Nathan, maybe you could post the code on codereview.stackexchange.com and then post a link to it in this answer.

Comment: @Geoff: I'll look it over to see if it has a public license. It may not be. Most of the code I touch related to other people is not open source.

Comment: Your example proves the opposite of what you think it proves. Had this code been commented, you would have been alerted to the fact that it implements a complex algorithm and that it requires more careful auditing than typical code does. So it should have been commented, and the commenting should have caused you to look at the code extra-carefully.

Comment: @David: Who and what are you talking about?

Comment: The question on which I am commenting. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 75):

Comments should explain why, not how.

`How` type comments are usually better dealt with using refactoring. Personally, I usually avoid comments in favor of refactoring.

Before:

```
# convert to cents
a = x * 100

# avg cents per customer 
avg = a / n

# add to list
avgs < avg
t += 1
```

after:

```
total_cents = total * 100
average_per_customer = total_cents / customer_count

track_average(average_per_customer)
```

Comment: I agree with the why not how part, and your refactoring works in this example, but with more complex code, no amount of variable/function renaming/refactoring is gonna have it make perfect sense, and comments will still be needed there.

Comment: Good example, but why is the system working with cents as opposed to dollars? That question becomes relevant in financial systems where you might see fractional currency come into play.

Comment: Hmmmm. Comments should primarily explain what code does, not how or why. I need to know what a function does, not why or how.

Comment: @Stuart the name of the function should say what it does.

Comment: @GSto, I couldn't disagree more.  If the code is complex, it should be broken into smaller methods/functions with appropriate names that describe the action.

Comment: You assume, that you have complete control over the code base.

Answer (score 32):

I declare your co-worker a heretic!  Where are my heretic-burnin' boots?

Obsessive commenting is bad and a maintenance headache, and comments are no replacement for well-named methods, classes, variables, etc.  But sometimes putting *why* something is the way it is can be immensely valuable for the poor idiot who has to maintain the code in six months -- particularly when that poor idiot winds up being you.

Some actual comments from the code I'm working on:

```
    // If this happens, somebody's been screwing around with the database definitions and
    // has removed the restriction that a given alarm may have only one entry in the 
    // notifications table.  Bad maintenance programmer!  Bad!  No biscuit!



    // If an alert is active on our side but inactive on theirs, that might mean
    // they closed the alert.  (Or that we just haven't told them about it yet.)  The
    // logic comes later; for now, we'll just compile it in a list.



    // If we know for a fact that an alarm isn't getting through, we're going to whine pretty
    // aggressively about it until it gets fixed.
```

Comment: +1 for nice comments. No amount of code can say "If this happens, somebody's been screwing around with the database definitions".

Comment: @Niphra, well, we _could_ throw a `SomebodyScrewedAroundWithDatabaseException`...

Comment: @Thorbjørn +1, If the code knows what's wrong darn well report it. The customers support tech's can probably reload their DB, and avoid a service call.

Comment: @Tim, as customers may see this, a more neutral naming might be appropriate.

Comment: Sure, remember: never use silly names. The customer will always see them.

Answer (score 29):

Ideally, code should be so well coded that it should be auto explicative. In the real world, we know that also very high quality code needs sometimes commenting.

What you should absolutely avoid is "comment-code redundancy" (comments that don't add anything to code):

```
i++; // Increment i by 1
```

Then, if there's a good (and maintained/aligned) code design and documentation, commenting is even less useful.

But in some circumstances comments can be a good aid in code readability:

```
while( foo )
{
     if( dummy )
     {
     }
     else // !dummy
     {
     }
} // end while( foo )
```

Don't forget that you have to maintain and keep in sync also comments... outdated or wrong comments can be a terrible pain! And, as a general rule, commenting too much can be a symptom of bad programming.

Comment: Good naming convention and well structured code will help you decrease the comments need. Don`t forget that each line of comments you add it's a new line to maintain!!

Comment: @Gabriel: that was already in my answer, look at the end.

Comment: @Lorenzo: sorry, I've read it and did not catch this one...

Comment: I hate when people use that second example in your question. `} //end while` just means the beginning of the while loop is so far away, you can't even see it, and there are no hints that the code you're looking at is in a loop. Heavy refactoring should be seriously preferred to comments about how the code is structured.

Comment: @Carson: while keeping blocks short is a well known rule, it doesn't mean that we always can apply it.

Comment: @Carson:  One of the projects I work on has insufficient code review, which lead to a collection of JSPs with a cyclomatic complexity of "OMFG JUST KILL YOURSELF."  Refactoring the bloody things represents days of work that need to be spent elsewhere.  Those `} // end while` comments can be a lifesaver.

Comment: @BlairHippo: "[A] code smell is any symptom in the source code of a program that possibly indicates a deeper problem". Of course the comment is a life saver, but the OMGWTF-loop is the aforementioned "deeper problem" and the necessity of the life saver is a clear indicator ;)

Comment: If you get value out of comments that could in principle be automatically generated, then you either need a better language or text editor.

Comment: @Winston: agree. If you have a powerful "intellisense", or a better language, you don't need this "code block comment". But if you don't have it...

Comment: @back2dos:  Point.  :-)

Comment: @back2dos Great comment

Comment: @lorenzo @blairhippo -- no matter what you say, it's still awful and I still hate it :)

Comment: @Carson: I tend to `} // while` even if the loop is short, simply because glancing at the word "while" is faster than looking at indentation levels, *even if* indentation is low and the block is short. For me it's visual texture to improve readability, and nothing more.

Comment: [joke]Whoaaa i++ increments by 1?!? Never knew that.. Thank god for that comment!![/joke]

Comment: @Lorenzo, why can't you keep blocks short by e.g. extracting methods, etc.?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: in my experience there are some __limit cases__ where splitting a function may result in less readable code, especially in some computational algorithms (like audio or video filters or data compression). Maintaining the full code in a single function __may__ greatly help understandability and readability. However, this is a question about comments, and not about the right length of blocks, so what's the point?

Comment: C-style languages that use braces to indicate blocks of code are intended to be terse.  Indenting is supposed to make pairs of braces obvious.  I really hate it when people clutter up their code by re-implementing BASIC flow control statements in their comments.  I don't know how they cope with Python, where there are no closing braces and *everything* is done with indentation.

Answer (score 26):

Categorically defining a method or process as a "code smell" is a "zealotry smell".  The term is becoming the new "considered harmful".

Please remember that all of these sort of things are supposed to be guidelines.

Many of the other answers give good advice as to when comments are warranted.

Personally I use very few comments. Explain the purpose of non-obvious processes and leave the occasional death-threat to anyone that might be considering altering things on their own that required weeks of tuning.

Refactoring everything until a kindergartner can understand it is likely not an efficient use of your time, and probably will not perform as well as a more concise version.

Comments don't affect run time,so the only negative issue to consider is the maintenance.

Comment: I thought "anti-pattern" was the new "considered harmful".  A code smell is just something that needs a closer review for possible cleanup.

Comment: I don't disagree that anti-pattern also qualifies.  They both get used that way with anti-pattern being used instead of smell when the design is complex enough that it is obviously a deliberate choice.  In either case I disagree with the concept that there is an absolute source of correct on these things.

Comment: +1 for "Refactoring everything until a kindergartner can understand it is likely not an efficient use of your time, and probably will not perform as well as a more concise version."

Answer (score 23):

The primary issue here is the meaning of the term "code smell".

Many people (including you, I think) understands a code smell to be something close to an error or at least something that needs to be fixed. Perhaps you think of it as a synonym to "anti-pattern".

**This is not the meaning of the term!**

The code smell metaphor originates from [Wards Wiki](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeSmell), and they stress:

> Note that a CodeSmell is a hint that something might be wrong, not a certainty. A perfectly good idiom may be considered a CodeSmell because it's often misused, or because there's a simpler alternative that works in most cases. Calling something a CodeSmell is not an attack; it's simply a sign that a closer look is warranted.

So what does it mean that comments are a code-smell: it means that when you see a comment, you should pause and think: "Hmmm, I sense a hint that something could be improved". Perhaps you can rename a variable, perform the "extract method"-refactoring -- or perhaps the comment is actually the best solution.

### **That is what it means for comments to be code smells.**

EDIT:
I just stumpled upon these two articles, which explains it better than me:

- [Apologies In code](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.TimOttinger.ApologizeIncode)
- [To Need Comments](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ToNeedComments)

Comment: I'm stunned that took 2 months for this answer to come up.  It demonstrates how widespread the misunderstanding of the term is.

Comment: The general case assertion is still wrong. You don't say, "I'm seeing commented code. That's a bad sign."

Comment: @Stuart: You're looking at two chunks of code, both with appropriate levels of comments. (This issue is not about the appropriate number of comments, it's about how you judge code based on the number of comments.) One has no comments, the other has tons. Which do you look more closely at? -- Comments are a sign that code is complicated and subtle and thus more likely to have issues.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 22):

In some cases, no amount of good naming, refactoring etc. can replace a comment. Just look at this real-world example (language is Groovy):

```
  response.contentType="text/html"
  render '{"success":true}'
```

Looks strange, doesn't it? Probably a copy-paste-error? Cries for a bugfix?

Now the same with comments:

```
  // DO NOT TOUCH THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES; the ExtJS UploadForm requires it exactly like that!!!
  response.contentType="text/html"  // must be text/html so the browser renders the response within the invisible iframe, where ExtJS can access it
  render '{"success":true}'         // ExtJS expects that, otherwise it will call the failure handler instead of the succss handler
```

Comment: function prime_extjs_uploadform() { response.contentType = 'text/html'; render '{ "success": true }'; } prime_extjs_uploadform();

Answer (score 21):

I think the rule is quite simple: imagine a complete stranger seeing your code. You probably will be a stranger to your own code in 5 years.
Try to minimize the mental effort to understand your code for this stranger.

Comment: +1 To any dev who hasn't been working on a single project long enough to experience this, believe me it **will** happen.  Anytime I learn this the hard way and have to relearn my own code, I don't let myself make the same mistake twice and comment it before I move on to something else.

Comment: No, you should imagine a psychopath who knows where you live: will they be happy to maintain your code?

Comment: I regularily become a psychopath when i see unreadable code.

Comment: 5 years? More like 5 minutes. ;)

Answer (score 11):

A good idea to have the right comments is to start with writing comments.

```
// This function will do something with the parameters, 
// the parameters should be good according to some rules.
myFunction(parameters)
{
    // It will do some things to get started.

    // It will do more with the stuff.

    // It will end doing things with the stuff.
}
```

This allows you to extract methods easily to even get rid of the comments,
**just let the code tell these things**! See how this is rewritten (cut/paste) in a very nice way:

```
// This function will do something with the parameters, 
// the parameters should be good according to some rules.
myfunction(parameters)
{
  var someThing = initializedWithSomething;

  doSomethingWith(someThing);

  doMoreWith(someThing);

  endDoingThingsWith(someThing);

  return someThing;
}

// This function will do some things to get started,
// the parameters should be good according to some rules.
doSomethingWith(parameters)
{
  parameters.manipulateInSomeWay();
  ... etc ...
}

... etc ...
```

For things that can't be separated just don't extract methods and type the code under the comments.

This is what I see as an useful way to keep commenting to a minimum, it's really useless to go commenting each line... Only document a single line if it's about a magic value initialization or  where it makes sense.

If parameters are used too much, then they should be private members in your class.

Comment: This is what I do. If you think you need comments, I can heartily recommend trying this as a replacement.

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is the usual "It depends" one.  Commenting code just to comment code is a smell.  Commenting code because you're using an obscure algorithm that's an order of magnitude faster saves the maintenance programmer (usually me 6 months after I wrote it) half a day of poking through the code to determine what it's doing.

Answer (score 10):

```
// Dear me in the future. Please, resolve this problem.
```

or

```
// You think this code was written by somebody else. 
// No, it wasn't. You ([some name]) did it.
```

Comment: Ah, heartfelt pleas to the future self.

Answer (score 8):

Code comments are definitely not a "code smell". This belief typically comes from the fact that comments can become stale (out of date) and can be difficult to maintain. However, having good comments which explain why the code is doing something a certain way can (and usually is) important for maintenance.

> Good comments make it easier to
>   understand what the code is doing and,
>   more important, why it is doing it a
>   particular way. Comments are meant to
>   be read by programmers and should be
>   clear and precise. A comment that is
>   hard to understand or incorrect isn’t
>   much better than having had no comment
>   at all.
>
> Adding clear and precise comments to
>   your code means that you don’t have to
>   rely on memory to understand the
>   “what” and “why” of a section of code.
>   This is most important when you look
>   at that code later on, or someone else
>   must look at your code. Because
>   comments become part of the textual
>   content of your code, they should
>   follow good writing principles in
>   addition to being clearly written.
>
> To
>   write a good comment, you should do
>   your best to document the purpose of
>   the code (the why, not how) and
>   indicate the reasoning and logic
>   behind the code as clearly as
>   possible. Ideally, comments should be
>   written at the same time as you write
>   the code. If you wait, you probably
>   won’t go back and add them.
>
> *[Sams Teach Yourself Visual C# 2010 in 24 Hours](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672331012), pp 348-349.*

Comment: Comments can become stale, but that's true for everything that's not verified by a compiler or a unit test, like the meaning of class, function and variable names.

Comment: @Lenny222: Yes, comments can become stale...which is usually indicative of lazy programmers. If the comment describes why a descision was made, why the code uses a particular algorithm for computation, or describes how the code functions, then there is no reason for the comment to become stale other than someone changing the implementation and not updating the comment accordingly -- which is equivalent to being lazy.

Comment: I agree. My point is, there is a risk of it becoming stale, yes. But when i have a function doBar() and after 3 years it doesn't "do bar", but it "does bar and foo except on wednesdays" then the meaning of functions can get stale too. And variable names. But i hope noone takes this for a reason to not give functions and variables meaningful names.

Answer (score 6):

If the code has been written in a particular way to avoid a problem present in a library (both a third-party library, or a library that comes with the compiler), then it makes sense to comment it.
It also make sense to comment code that needs to be changed in future versions, or when using a new version of a library, or when passing from PHP4 to PHP5, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Even the most well-written book still likely has an introduction and chapter titles. Comments in well-documented code are still useful to describe high-level concepts, and explain how the code is organized.

Comment: Comments of this sort give nice visual cues so you don't have to read every line to find the start of the section you're looking for.  As my grandfather used to say, "everything in moderation."

Answer (score 4):

Of honorable mention is the anti-pattern:

It's my impression that sometimes FLOSS license preamples are frequently used **in lieu** of file documentation. The GPL/BSDL makes a nice filler text, and after that you seldomly see any other comment block.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the idea that writing comments to explain the code are bad. This completely ignores the fact that code has bugs. It might be clear what the code *does* without comments. It's less likely to be clear what the code is *supposed* to do. Without comments how do you know if the results are wrong, or they're being used incorrectly?

The comments should explain the *intent* of the code, so that if there is a mistake, someone reading the comments+code has a chance of finding it.

I generally find myself writing inline comments *before* I write the code. This way it's clear what I'm trying to write code to do, and reduces getting lost in an algorithm without really knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Unit tests help a lot to determine if the results are wrong. If you read some code and think it does X when in reality it does Y, then it's possible the code isn't written in a readable enough way. I'm not sure what you mean about the results being used incorrectly. A comment will not protect you against someone consuming your code in strange ways.

Comment: "If you read some code and think it does X when in reality it does Y" That's not what I said. I'm talking about understanding what code *does* do, but not what it's *supposed* to do. Let's say you suspect an off-by-one error. How do you know the off-by-one error isn't in the consuming code instead or this code? Comments explain the *intent* of the code, which helps enormously with tracking down bugs.

Comment: On the other hand, the comments might only tell you what the code was supposed to do *as of the time the comments were written.* The code itself may be telling you what it's supposed to do *now.* Comments don't compile. You can't test comments. They may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Comments that are put in because someone thinks it's ok to have 700 lines in one method are a smell.

Comments that are there because you know if you don't put in a comment, someone will make the same mistake yet again are a smell.

Comments put in because some code analysis tool demands it are also a smell.

People that won't *ever* put in a comment, or write even a little help for other developers are also a smell. I'm amazed at how many people won't write stuff down, but will then turn around and acknowledge they can't remember what they did 3 months ago. I don't like to write docs, but I like to have to tell people the same thing over and over again even less.

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer with a question of my own.  Can you find the bug in the uncommented code below?

tl;dr: The next person to maintain your code might not be as godlike as you are.

```
 [org 0x7c00]

 main:
  mov ah, 0x0e
  mov bx, string
  call strreverse
  call print

 stop:
  jmp $

 strreverse:
  pusha
  mov dx, bx
  mov cx, 0

 strreverse_push:
  mov al, [bx]
  cmp al, 0
  je strreverse_pop
  push ax
  add bx, 1
  add cx, 1
  jmp strreverse_push

 strreverse_pop:
  mov bx, dx

 strreverse_pop_loop:
  cmp cx, 0
  je strreverse_end
  pop ax
  mov [bx], al
  sub cx, 1
  add bx, 1
  jmp strreverse_pop_loop

 strreverse_end:
  popa
  ret

 print:
  pusha

 print_loop:
  mov al, [bx]
  cmp al, 1
  je print_end
  int 0x10
  add bx, 1
  jmp print_loop

 print_end:
  popa
  ret
 string:
  db 'Boot up', 0

 times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
 dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: But way in this day and age are you not using a high level langage?

Comment: @Ian: The program is an IBM-PC bootloader.  You *can't* write it in anything other than assembly, because you need total control of exactly where the program is located in RAM, where the last short appears, and some of the hardware interrupts.  Seriously, get yourself a copy of NASM.  Assemble it, write it to the boot sector of a floppy or USB stick, and boot it.  Though you'll probably find it doesn't work as expected because of the bug.  Now find the bug...  Regardless, I'm sure that in 20 years from now, people will ask the same thing of uncommented Java.

Comment: Surely the code could be written in C or C++, and the binary assembled from the C object code and some external tool.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Have a look at this page on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/boot-loader.aspx - "high-level languages don’t have the necessary instructions".  Not only that, but you've only got 512 bytes to play with in a bootloader.  Sometimes you just have to get directly to the hardware.

Comment: So which comments would you have added (without knowing there was a bug in it), and would they help you spot the bug?
For bonus points: How would unit-tests have helped you?

Comment: When coding assembly, I'd do what everyone else does - comment every single line with what it's doing.  The line in question would have had the comment "check if letter is 0", as the code uses C-style 0-terminated strings.  With that comment in place, it's easy to see that the code is doing a cmp with 1, which means it either gets stuck in an infinite loop or prints garbage until it hits a random 1 in RAM. I might also have added a comment about the fact that the strings were 0-terminated, which isn't apparent from the code.  Is there such a thing as automated unit testing for assembly coding?

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep a balance between code and comments... Usually I try to add some comments that resume a block of code. Not because I won't be able to understand the code (well, that also), but because I can read faster my own code and locate specific sections where the important stuff it's happening.

Anyway, my own personal criteria is "when in doubt, comment". I prefer to have a redundant line than a completely cryptic line that I'm not going to be able to understand. I can always remove comments on a code review, after a while (and I usually do)

Also, comments are quite helpful adding "caveats" like "Be careful! If the format of the input is not ASCII, this code will have to change!"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "comments that resume a block of code"?

Answer (score 2):

Reading this I am reminded on something that I first read (from a longer list, preserved by taking photocopies) some decades back:

> Real programmers don't write comments - if it was hard to write it should be hard to read

A rather older smell methinks.

Answer (score 2):

I think code commenting gets a very poor start to life. I don't know about these days, but when I was first being taught programming at school I got assignments of the nature of "Write a program that prints the numbers one to ten on separate lines. Make sure you comment your code." You'd get marked down if you didn't add comments because commenting your code is a GOOD THING.

But what is there to say about such a trivial process? So you end up writing the classic

```
i++; // add one to the "i" counter.
```

just to get a decent grade and, if you've any nous at all, instantly forming a very low opinion of code comments.

Code commenting is not a GOOD THING. It's a SOMETIMES NECESSARY THING, and Thomas Owens in the top answer provides an excellent explanation of the situations in which it's necessary. However, these situations rarely crop up in homework-type assignments.

In many ways, adding a comment should be considered a last-resort choice, when what needs to be said cannot be said clearly in the active parts of the programming language. Although object naming can go stale, various human and computer lack-of-feedback mechanisms make it easy to forget to maintain comments and consequently comments go stale much more quickly than active code. For that reason, where a choice is possible, changing code to make it clearer should always be preferred to annotating unclear code with comments.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that bad comment habits start with early programming classes.  -1 for concluding that comments are only a last resort choice.

Answer (score 1):

### Of course comments are a code smell...

every programmer knows we all eventually [turn insane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) due to the amount of work, debugging, or just plain madness we run into.

"Do this!" your project manager says.

You respond, "It can't be done."

They say, "Then we will find someone else to do it."

You say, "OK, well maybe it can be done."

And then spend the next X number of days.. weeks.. months.. trying to figure it out. Throughout the process, you will try and fail, and try and fail. **We all do this.** The true answer is there are two types of programmers, those that comment and those that don't.

1) Those that do are either making their own job easier by documenting for future reference, commenting out failed routines that didn't work (the smell is not deleting them after finding the one that works.), or breaking up the code with comment formatting to *hopefully* make it a bit easier to read or understand. Seriously, I can't blame them. But in the end, they snap and then you have this:
`// dammit this code sucks! swear! curse! i hate it! i am going to write something here to vent my anger!!!!`

2) Those that don't are either pretending to be a superhero, or [are living in a cave](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/in-programming-one-is-the-loneliest-number.html). They simply have reckless disregard for others, themselves, and could care less about the code, or what meaning it could possibly have for later.

Now don't get me wrong.. self-documenting variables and functions can avoid this entirely.. and ***trust me*** you can never do enough code-cleanup. But the simple truth is that as long as you keep backups, you can **ALWAYS** delete comments.

Comment: In response to 1.  The true smell in commented routines is  not deleting them right away when you decide they may be dead ends and want to try something different---this is because they should be available in version control if you decide to revisit them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that not using *some* comments in your code is a code smell. While I agree that code should be self documenting as much as possible, you hit a certain point where you are going to see code that makes no sense regardless of how well the code is written. I've seen some code in business applications where the comments are pretty much mandatory because:

1. You need to do something on a case by case basis and there's no good logic for it.
2. The code will likely change in a year or two when the laws are changed and you want to find it again quickly.
3. Someone edited the code in the past because they didn't understand what the code was doing.

Also, company style guides might tell you to do something a certain way - if they say that your could should have comments outlining what blocks of code in a function is doing, then include the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big fundamental difference between comments and code: comments are a way for people to communicate ideas to other people, whereas code is primarily meant for the computer. There are many aspects in "code" that's also only for humans, like naming and indentation. But comments are written strictly for humans, by humans.

Therefore, writing comments is every bit as difficult as any written human communication! The writer should have a clear conception of who the audience is, and what kind of text they will need. How can you know who will read your comments in ten, twenty years? What if the person is from a completely different culture? Etc. I hope everybody understands this.

Even inside the small homogeneous culture I live in, it's just so difficult to communicate ideas to other people. Human communication usually fails, except by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with your coworker.  I always say that if I comment my code, it means that I'm worried that *I* won't be able to figure out *my own code* in the future. This is a bad sign.

The only other reason I sprinkle comments into the code is to call out something that doesn't seem to make sense.

Those comments usually take the form of something like:

```
//xxx what the heck is this doing??
```

or

```
// removed in version 2.0, but back for 2.1, now I'm taking out again
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, the comment may reflect the fact that the code is addressing a complex algorithm where the code becomes inherently not obvious or because the code is doing something odd due to factors beyond your control (e.g. interacting with an external service).

Comment: Very true. There are reasons why good code might not be obvious. Most of the time though perplexing code is perplexing because it's written in an obfuscated way.

Comment: Seems like you've not written code for embedded processors where you only have 32k to play in, and things DO you a bid obscure. Comments are life-savers.

Answer (score 0):

Code comments giving, where applicable, units of function arguments and returns, structure fields, even local variables can be very handy. Remember the Mars Orbiter!

Comment: Much better to build the units into the variable names, so the poor programmer doesn't have to remember them.  Instead of 'double length // in meters' say 'double length_m'.  Best of all is to use a more powerful language, so you can simply say Length l; Force f; Torque t = l * f; print(t.in(Torque.newtonMeter));

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my rule-of-thumb:**

- Write the code and store a short summary of the code in a separate document.
- Leave the code alone for several days to work on something else.
- Return to the code.  If you can't immediately understand what it's supposed to do, add the summary to the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Educate your co-worker about the [Literate Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) technique.

Answer (score 0):

No, comments are not a code smell, they are just a tool that can be abused.

Examples of *good* comments:

// I think this is in cm. Further investigation needed!

// This is a clever way of doing X

// The list is guaranteed to be non-empty here

Comment: The third one is a bad comment IMO. Why not `Assert(list.IsEmpty)`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos IMO `Assert(!list.isEmpty())` is not exactly a contract as in the third comment, but simply behavior (i.e. "throw IllegalArgumentException if the argument is empty") that must be unit-tested like any other program logic. Note the subtle difference with the comment, which states _when_ the method can be used, but specifies no behavior if the precondition is not met. Even better than the comment would be to enforce compile-time contracts. But this exceeds the scope of my answer ;)

Comment: You should not be able to exercise `Assert`s, since they describe things that should not ever happen, even if the public API receives invalid arguments.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I retract my opinion. Here is what [Sunacle has to say about assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html). It seems you were right. Well, you learn something every day!

Answer (score 0):

However code that cannot be understood at all it a much **bigger** code smell…

> Please give me clean code to work on,
>   however
>   if that is not an option, I
>   would rather have “dirty” code with
>   comments
>   than dirty code without
>   comments.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the words have been taken out of my mouth.  But I suppose to sum it all up: the point of comments is to give a high-level description/explanation of what the code is doing.

Moreover, here are a few examples of how I use comments:

- as headings, to indicate the general purpose of a section of code
- to note where I have cribbed code from and thereby avoid plagiarism
- occasionally at the ends of blocks, to remind of what block they're the end of
- to point out that code that may look suspicious is what's intended (e.g. those odd times when a switch case falls through)
- to explain the maths behind an algorithm

Answer (score 0):

No one said this so far in this thread, so I will:

Type names, variable names, function names, method names and comments are just metadata about your code, and has nothing to do with the machine code that the compiler generates (except the names of the exported and debug symbols of course).

Type names and variable names are your nouns, function and method names are your verbs, with these you describe steps to be done. Comments are for everything else.

Some examples:

```
double temperature; // In Kelvins.


/**
 * Returns true if ray hits the triangle
 */
bool castRayOnTriangle(Triangle t, Ray r)
{
    //...
    if (determinant == 0)
    {
        /* The ray and the triangle are parallel, no intersection possible.*/
        return false;
    }
    //...
}


/* X algorithm. Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/... for details.*/
<implementation of something difficult to understand for the layman algorithm. >
```

Comments may bacome obsolete, if not updated, but variable and function names can become obsolete too. I recently encountered a `bufPtr` field in a C structure, which has nothing to do with buffers or pointers. And I saw a `inflateBuffer` function that does not decompress a deflated data but a complete GZIP file... These are as annoying as outdated comments.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like too many answers consider programming in teams.  I'm a senior developer and I tend to write comments aimed at explaining what is otherwise simple for me to understand.

I see it as a form of posthumous team communication or education. I encourage the team to look through code they are using, but maybe haven't written to understand it better.

A couple of examples just from this week (PHP code):

```
//Pattern for finding jpeg photos
//Case insensitive pattern for jpg and jpeg
const PATTERN_PHOTO = "*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[jJ][pP][eE][gG]}";
```

I'd hope the name `PATTERN_PHOTO` would be helpful later in code to explain what it does, but without the comments how clear would it be to a junior developer what this specific pattern does?

Same set of code:

```
//Ignore . and .. directories in Linux
if($file != "." && $file != "..")
```

There's an expectation that our developers know PHP, but not that they understand the Linux OS we are using for hosting.

So, I find these comments to actually increase the overall efficiency of our team for the very little time it takes to write them.

- There's less cases of people rewriting code simply because they don't understand how it works. "I didn't understand how it did what it was supposed to, so I fixed it." Seriously, I've had to deal with this before.
- There are less questions asked about individual pieces of code.  Answering the questions just once, usually requires looking up the code and the time for me to re-familiarize myself with it. And sometimes I'll get the same question from more than one person weeks apart. (*Yes, it would be on things as simple as the examples above*)
- Other developers are encouraged and guided to learn on their own.  I'd expect that if they came across `//Ignore . and .. directories in Linux` they'd likely hop on Google and would suddenly understand Linux a little bit better.