# How to deal with tautology in comments?

Tags: programming-practices, documentation, language-agnostic

Sometimes I find myself in situations when the part of code that I am writing is (or *seems to be*) so self-evident that its name would be basically repeated as a comment:

```
class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the update.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri UpdateLocation { get; set; };
}
```

(C# example, but please refer to the question as language-agnostic).

A comment like that is useless; what am I doing wrong? Is it the choice of the name that is wrong? How could I comment parts like this better? Should I just skip the comment for things like this?

Comment: Note:  I would consider "The location of the update" to be very vague unless it is crystal clear what "an update" is.  Do the system support other kinds of URI's than URL's?

Comment: It is an `Uri`, so it is meant to support everything that `Uri` supports (at least I think it is implicated).

Comment: That specific example looks like a generated code comment (ghostdoc, anyone?). Possibly because of an overly zealous adherence to certain tool warnings (stylecop, anyone?).

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear enough, this is just an example that I made up.

Comment: `return result # returns result`

Comment: Instead of just restating the method name with spaces why not describe it better.  ie This is the URI that will be queried to find updates for the Foo module.

Comment: The way to deal with tautology in comments is the way to deal with tautology in comments.  (This is a comment.)

Comment: This isn't really a comment, it's actually *documentation* written in the form of a comment. Different rules apply to API documentation than they do to inline code comments.

Comment: I agree with @CodyGray. This is documentation, specifically API documentation. At a minimum, such documentation should help a new person looking at the method in isolation *understand what the method actually does.* The example comment you give fails this metric; it should say something more along the lines of *"Returns the URI of the update from where the foo is barred"*, instead of simply restating the obvious.

Comment: This is simply an example of poor API Documentation, not code comments.  My C# XML formatting for a property like this would look something like "Gets or Sets a Uri that can be used to access this object's update server."

Comment: I once came across legacy code `page=0;    //Sets the page to 0`. That was my all time favorite example of this;-)

Comment: @RexKerr - Personally, I feel the way to deal with tautology is self-explanatory, pretty much by definition. Besides, the first rule of tautology club is the first rule of tautology club.

Comment: Useful alternative that demonstrates how to turn a poor comment into a good one: `// This is an adjective, not a verb. Provided for consumers that need to retrieve the update location because [x]`

Comment: See my previous answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137575/do-we-need-obvious-method-documentation-information/137614#137614

Comment: `Display *display; /* the display */`

Comment: "A comment like that is useless; what am I doing wrong?"  If you code so that the comment is useless, you are doing something right.

Comment: There are different comments. Some types between source lines, let's call them "inline comments" help you to understand _how_ your code works. Some other types, like that one in the question, are API documentations that help the user of your API to understand _how to use_ your code. Whereas in the first case there is not much sense to use tautology, in the second case there might be.

Comment: Code in such a way as to make the comments useless tautologys, then remove the comments. Use comments for why, use comments in cases where the language is week and can not express something (pre/post conditions).

Comment: @CodyGray has the correct answer...  The picked answer is not the correct answer...

Comment: @Paul, there is no picked answer at the moment (nor when you commented). I initially picked one, but removed the tick because there was a lot of interest towards the question and I didn't want to discourage anyone from answering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most projects I work on, there isn't a significant amount of time to write detailed comments on every single class member.

That doesn't mean there isn't time for comments; on the contrary, there's plenty of time for tautological comments that puke back a rephrased version of whatever's being commented. They work great as a **starting point**.

Especially given Visual Studio's usage of comments accompanying [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), it's a good idea to start with a short bit of information about the field:

```
class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the update.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri UpdateLocation { get; set; };
}
```

And then as you continue to code, *when* you can't remember whether `UpdateLocation` was the location that the update took place, or the location that the update is being sent to, you'll have to revisit the code. It is at this point that you should add that additional information:

```
class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Uri location where the update took place.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri UpdateLocation { get; set; };
}
```

If ever another programmer asks you about details on a field, update the comments with that information:

> What sort of update should `Example.UpdateLocation` be used to store?

```
class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Uri location where the Foo update took place.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri UpdateLocation { get; set; };
}
```

Just like a program has bugs, good comments have bugs that need to be iteratively worked out. The purpose of comments is to assist in understanding code when you revisit it six months later and can't remember anything about how the program works.

And just like programming, your comments have to start somewhere. Tautological comments are the `Hello World!` of comments, as you practice writing and updating documentation, your starting documentation will become more and more resilient.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to actually give an alternative comment; rather than just tautological answers.

Comment: This is actually the best answer so far.

Comment: In my current project I've been hit more than I can count by the lack of comments on a large legacy code base. 

Something You as an author, think is blatantly self-explanatory method name for something You consider to be rather obvious functionality, might not be just as self-documenting in three months time to another developer.

Documentation on methods, properties and fields should try to put a context to the wider picture and this answer explains the best process of reaching that goal, I've seen so far.

Comment: @RolandTepp, I totally understand where you're coming from. And I agree completely. The problem as I see it is that many programmers see comments and documentation as something that happens after the code is complete and ready to ship, rather than as something that happens with the code as part of the development process, requiring bug tracking and support hours along with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 54):

Comments should *never* duplicate your code. Comments should not answer the "*how?*" question, but only "*why?*" and "*what?*". Why such an algorithm is chosen, what are the implicit assumptions here (unless your language is powerful enough to express it with type system, contracts and alike), what is a reason for doing this thing at all, etc.

I'd recommend to take a look at the Literate Programming practice for an inspiration.

Comment: +1 - this is the answer! We don't need comments like "Declare variables", "Increment counter" (in a loop) etc.

Comment: so in the OP's example, what would be a good comment?

Comment: @stijn, I do not know - it is (obviously) missing from the code. Something that only the author of the code know about its purpose and limitations.

Comment: Perhaps some comment like

// Updates the raiseShielders according to the levelOfAttack (passed as a URL)

Comment: The most important question a comment should answer is "[WTF?](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/2/15/The-only-valid-measurement-of-code-quality-WTFsminute)"

Comment: Not all comments on how are bad. For example if you are implementing an algorithm that has a lot of details and can get hard to follow, it would be nice to have an overall of the algorithm as comment at the top of the function (which is "how" the algorithm is implemented)

Comment: @Shahbaz, there are better ways of getting an outline explained - e.g., as in some of the literate programming tools (`web`, `cweb`, `noweb`), or just by using a more appropriate level of abstraction and a more expressive programming language, so that the code structure would be the same as the outline, with details given below in a proper order. Otherwise it is very easy to get this outline description out of sync with the actual definition.

Answer (score 53):

Comments should *describe* the code, not duplicate it. This header comment just duplicates. Leave it out.

Comment: +1: I think I understand what you mean, but I don't agree with whay you said :-) As far as possible, *code* should describe code, whereas comments should describe your reasoning.

Comment: @Kramii, unfortunately, code is incapable of *describing* the code, even if you're coding in Agda. No languages are as powerful and expressive as the natural language. And often you'll need plots, graphs, tables, complex formulas to describe the code - barely possible without a proper literate programming.

Comment: @SK-logic: I disagree. A long method is less self-describing than a short method that calls a series of well-named subroutines.

Comment: @Kramii, sorry, I cannot see what you disagree with and how your comment is related to whay I've said. My point is that a lot of information should be provided alongside with your code which is totally *missing* from the code itself. All the history behind decisions you've made, all the relevant references to the papers, etc. - there are no language elements for expressing such things. And long vs. short methods/functions/subroutines/whatever is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @SK-logic, what Kramii says means: "The code should be easy to read and understand itself" and all the graphs etc that you are mentioning falls into what he says as: "the comments should describe your reasoning"

Comment: @Shahbaz, and how is it relevant to long vs. short? Code dose not *describe* itself, since description refers to the semantics missing from the code. Reasoning is just a part of a description, how can it be opposed to it?

Comment: @SK-logic, Our terminologies are different. For example `path = get_shortest_path(a, b); remove_path(path);` describes what it does, but doesn't say the reasoning. At least that's what _I_ understand by the word "describe"

Comment: It's true that a lot of information must be provided alongside with the code, but that doesn't mean that it must be intertwined with the code. Programmers are just one of many roles that collaboratively produce documentation of a project.

Comment: Don't just leave it out, come up with a better comment. There is a good reason why Visual Studio encourages you to add comments in a specific format as these can then be used to generate XML documentation  for your entire .NET code (which can then be transformed into meaningful help files and documentation). There are *always* ways to describe something in a meaningful way, even if it seems obvious to you what it is.

Comment: @Ando, if it is not embedded into a code, it is *doomed* to get out of sync. I've never seen a non-literate code documentation which is 100% up to date and correct.

Comment: @SK-logic, you're right, synching is an issue, but in the code it's buried and it will only be read with a lot of difficulty and by very few people, if any.

Comment: @Ando, just use the right tools to extract documentation from the code. Or turn the code itself into a documentation. Literate programming is quite a powerful and flexible thing.

Answer (score 36):

**Leave them out!**

Normally, it is good practice to remove comments where the information expressed in them is already present elsewhere. If you can express the purpose of a method clearly and unambiguously by giving it a good name then [there is no need for a comment](http://yagni.net/2012/03/15/some-comments-on-comments/).

**Put them in!**

Your example illustrates two exceptions to this rule:

First, "UpdateLocation" may (depending on context) be ambiguous. In that case, you either need to give it a better name or provide a comment to remove the ambiguity. Improving the name is generally the better option, but this is not always possible (when you are implementing a published API, for example).

Second, the "///" in C# indicates a comment that is intended to be used to auto-generate documentation. The IDE uses these comments to tool-tips, and there are tools (Sandcastle) that can generate help files and so forth from these comments. As such, there are arguments for inserting these comments even if the methods they document already have descriptive names. Even then, however, many experienced developers would frown on the duplication of information. The deciding factor should be the needs of those for whom the documentation is intended.

Comment: This is the best answer.  You should be able to figure out exactly what the property will be used for when you are consuming the Example class and hover over the property.

Comment: In these situations I strive (and often fail), to add at least either `<remarks/>` or `<see/>` so at to provide some additional content.  The `<summary/>` is still duplicated, but the comment overall is not completely useless.

Answer (score 20):

I strongly disagree with the "don't write comments" responses. Why? Let me point out by changing your example a bit.

```
public Uri UpdateLocation ();
```

So what does this function do:

- Does it return the "update location"?
  or
- Does it "update" the location and return the new location?

You can see that without a comment there is ambiguity. A newcommer can easily make the mistake.

In your example, it is a property so the "get/set" methods reveal that the second option is incorrect and it does indeed mean "update location" and not "update the location". But it is far too easy to make this mistake, especially in cases of ambiguous words such as "update". Play safe. Don't confuse someone new to this just for saving a few seconds of your time.

Comment: I don't think anyone is advocating don't write any comments at all. Most/all are saying "write appropriate comments", which the UpdateLocation example would come under.

Comment: `Uri UpdateLocation()` would be rejected by code review and changed to either `Uri GetUpdateLocation()` or to `void UpdateLocation()`.

Comment: It is argued by some that you can (almost) always remove ambiguity be improving the method name or by refactoring. For example, call the method "GetUpdateLocation" if that is what you mean, or refactor the code into two methods, the first "UpdateLocation" to update the location and "GetLocation" to get the new location. That said, I can see why this isn't always a good use of time, and a well-placed comment might be a better bet. As @Ozz said, nobody says "don't write comments".

Comment: this answer seems to be missing that the example is a property that, by definition, gets and sets

Comment: @avakar I think that's only true if that is your style guide. For example, Qt never does "get..." functions: getters are nouns.

Comment: @avakar: Agree with the sentiment, but as this is a C# property (get and set are automatically synthesised and have the same name) renaming to `GetUpdateLocation` would result in code like `GetUpdateLocation = somelocation`.  `LocationOfUpdate` would be a better name, which removes the ambiguity.  The basic problem is that the OP used a verb prefix instead of a noun.  Leading verbs are presumed to indicate the action of a method.

Comment: @avakar  Yes it would be rejected ina code review. In fact it ought to be rejected in a self-review but not everybody looks at their code critically. In fact if you writea comment , you will immediately know that you havent named your function correctly and change it before it is too late. Which is why you should comment, even if it seems obvious. It may not really be obvious, and commenting can force you to relook.

Comment: @Kramii. Oz. Yes there are quite a few "leave it out" responses which say that in ceratin conditions you can leave them out. Im saying that it shouldnt be discretionary. It should be a standard. How much time and effort does it take to wirt one line.

Comment: @Ant, we were talking about a function, not a property.

Comment: @DPD, "How much time and effort does it take to wirt one line" how much effort does it take to maintain it? How much screen estate does it waste? How much time does it waste when it ultimately gets out of sync with the code and start to confuse developers?

Comment: The method returns a value, and has a verb-phrase name. This is the problem. It should have a noun-phrase name. e.g. 'Uri LocationOfUpdate()'. Not GetUpdateLocation, do you say “what is your GetLocation?”?

Comment: @avakar: Ah yes, quite right.  But the rest of the comment stands, as richard says - don't lead a function name with a verb unless the function performs that verb.

Comment: @richard The problem is that `update location` is both a verb phrase and a (composed) noun in the English language.

Comment: Uri LocationOfPreviousUpdate(); /*or*/ void UpdateTheLocation(); /*you don't need comments*/ I do not agree to the I need comments because I write code that is hard to understand, because I chose ambiguousness symbol names.

Answer (score 14):

`/// <summary>` blocks are **used for generating documentation for [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) and API documentation**.

Thus, if this is a public-facing API, you should *always* include at least a `<summary>` comment, even if the purpose of the function *should be* self-evident to readers.

However, this is the exception to the rule; in general, just remember to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) *(Don't Repeat Yourself)*.

Answer (score 5):

Do fill comments like that **only if** you know how you'd benefit from stuff like that; otherwise just wipe them.

<sub>To me, case of *clear benefit* was when there was an automated check for missing comments **and** I was using that check to detect code where important information needed to be filled; for this I was indeed filling some *placeholders* - just to make sure that tool report does not contain "false alarms".</sub>

I think there is always a way to **[avoid blatant duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)**. Over years I've come to using couple "template fillers" for cases like yours - mostly like *self-descriptive name* and *see above*.

For this particular example, I would use something of "self-descriptive kind" (assuming it's not the case where wiping out would do the job), like that:

```
class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Self descriptive method name.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri UpdateLocation { get; set; };
}
```

<sub>Example when I could use *see above* kind fillers would be [Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javadoc/info) comments that require dedicated fields for return value, parameters and exceptions. Quite frequently, I find that it makes better sense to describe most or even all these in single summary sentence, *method that returns <describe what is returned> for provided parameters <describe parameters>*. In cases like that, I fill in formally required fields with plain *see above*, pointing reader to summary description.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Here's a question I like to ask myself when thinking about whether to add a comment into a section of code: What can I convey that would help the next person understand the overall *intent* of the code better, so that they can update, fix, or extend it faster and more reliably?

Sometimes the correct answer to this question is that there is nothing much you can add at that point in the code, because you have already selected names and conventions that make the intent about as obvious as it can be. That means you've written solid self-documenting code, and that inserting a comment there would likely detract more than it would help. (Note that redundant comments can actually damage code reliability over time by slowing falling out of sync with the real code over time and thus making it harder to decipher the real intent.

However, in almost any program and in any programming language, you are going to encounter points where certain critical concepts and decisions made by the original programmer -- by you -- will no longer be apparent in the code. This is pretty much unavoidable because a good programmer *always* programs for the future -- that is, not just to make the program work once, but to make all of its many future fixes and versions and extensions and modifications and ports and who knows what to *also* work correctly. That latter set of goals is a lot harder, and requires a lot more thinking to do well. It is also very hard to express well in most computer languages, which are more focused on functionality -- that is, on saying what does *this* version of the program need to do, right now, in order to make it satisfactory.

Here's a simple example of what I mean. In most languages, a quick in-line search of a small data structure will have enough complexity that someone looking at it for the first time likely will not recognized immediately what it is. That's an opportunity for a good comment, because you can add something about the *intent* of your code that a later reader will likely appreciate immediately as helpful for deciphering the details.

Conversely, in languages such as the logic-based language Prolog, expressing the search of a small list can be so incredibly trivial and succinct that *any* comment you might add would just be noise. So, good commenting is necessarily context dependent. That includes factors such as the strengths of the language you are using and the overall program context.

The bottom line is this: Think to the future. Ask yourself what is important and obvious to you about how the program should be understood and modified in the future.[1]

For those parts of your code that are truly self documenting, comments just add noise and increase the coherency problem for future versions. So don't add them there.

But for those parts of your code where you made a critical decision from several options, or where the code itself is complex enough that its purpose is obscure, please, add your special knowledge in the form of a comment. A good comment in such a case is one that lets some future programmer know what must be kept the same -- that is the concept of an invariant assertion, incidentally -- and what is OK to change.

---

[1] This goes beyond the issue of comments, but it's worth bringing up: If you find that you have a very crisp idea of how your code could change in the future, you should likely think beyond just making a comment and embed those parameters within the code itself, since that will almost always be a more reliable way to ensure the reliability of future versions of your code than trying to use comments to steer some unknown future person in the right direction. At the same time you also want to avoid overgeneralizing, since humans are notoriously bad at predicting the future, and that includes the future of program changes. So, try to define and capture reasonable and well-proven dimensions of future at all levels of program design, but don't let it get you distracted into an exercise in excessive generalization that is unlikely to pay of in the long term.

Answer (score 3):

In my own code, I will frequently leave comment tautologies in place, including the particularly egregious ones like:

```php
<?php
// return the result
return $result;
?>
```

... which obviously contribute little in terms of making the code more comprehensible from an explanatory perspective.

In my mind, though, these comments still have value, **if they help to maintain the visual consistency of the color patterns in your syntax highlighter**.

I think of code as having a structure that is very similar to the English language, in that there are "sentences" and "paragraphs" (even though a "paragraph" may consist entirely of a single "sentence"). I usually include a line-break and one-line summary above each "paragraph". For example:

```php
<?php
//get the id of the thing
$id = $_POST['id'];

//query the things out of the the database
$things = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Things WHERE `id` = $id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //create a proper Thing object or whatever
    $things[] = new Thing($row);
}

//return the things
return $things;
?>
```

(Ignore the incomplete code, SQL injections, etc. You get the idea.)

To me, the final comment genuinely adds value to the code, simply because it helps to visually delineate one "paragraph" from another by maintaining a consistent coloring scheme.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the syntax highlighting to work in my answer here. If some editor can come in behind me and get it working, I'd really appreciate it, given that the colors are significant to my argument.

Comment: I added [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Comments should be used to do one of the following.

1. Information for document generators to grab. This can't be understated, this is extremely important.
2. Warnings to why a piece of code is the way it is, and what other considerations. I've dealt with code written in 2 programming languages. One key part of this was to have a common structure between the two languages. A comment at both locations informing the user that if they change this number, they also need to change another is extremely helpful.
3. Write notes to explain why a particularly weird looking piece of code is the way it is. If you had to think about how to get a piece of code to work in a particular way, and the solution isn't evident from the beginning, it's probably worth an explanation as to what you were trying to do.
4. Labeling inputs/outputs, if they aren't clear. It's always good to know what your inputs are expected to be, and what format they are in.

Comments should not be used to do the following:

1. Explain things that are extremely obvious. I once saw legacy code like this: `page=0; // Sets the page to 0`. I think any competent individual could figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the tautology but keep the comment, I would comment properties and variable names by giving a sample value, so that the usage is clearly understood:

```
property UpdateLocation:TUpdateLocation;  // url="http://x/y/3.2/upd.aspx",proto=http
```

Now I know exactly what goes in there, and from the comment, I have a clear idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on the purpose of the comments.

If they're to be used to generate documentation for use by the team building it (or if they're just inline comments to explain things), then I think it's acceptable to leave that out. It can be safely assumed that it's self-explanatory; and when it's not, there are other team members nearby who can explain it. Of course, if it turns out it's not self-evident for a lot of people, you should add it in.

If the comments will generate documentation for some geographically distant team, then I would put every bit of documentation in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this topic has been discussed fairly extensively under names like "comments: anti-patterns", or "are comments a code smell?" ([one example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell)).

I tend to agree with the general idea that comments should add new information, not duplicate.  By adding trivial comments like that, you are violating DRY, and decreasing the signal to noise ratio of the code.  I tend to find high-level comments explaining the responsibilities, rationale behind, and example usage of the class much more useful than per-property comments (especially superfluous ones).

Personally, in your example, I would leave comment out (if there really is nothing useful to add about the property).

Answer (score 0):

If you can write code that does not require comments then you have achieved programming nirvana!.

The less comments your code *requires* the better the code!

Comment: This is not possible (and never will). There is always a lot of stuff left behind the code - implicit assumptions, architectural decisions, long chains of mathematical transforms ending up in a specific algorithm, etc.

Comment: Perhaps "Hello World!" is programmer nirvana then...

Comment: :-} -- Its something that is very rarely achieved -- the point is if your struggling to find a comment that adds meaning then just be pleased with yourself its means your code is just right!

Answer (score 0):

> A comment like that is useless; what am I doing wrong?

It only seems useless if you already know what `UpdateLocation` does. Is "update" here a verb or a noun adjunct? That is, is this something that updates the location, or is it the location of the update? One might infer the latter from the fact that `UpdateLocation` is apparently a property, but the larger point is that sometimes it doesn't hurt to explicitly state something that seems obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-compiled documentation aside, code should document itself, so that comments should only document where the code is not enough to document itself.

Answer (score -1):

"Location" is kind of obvious, but "Update" could be a bit vague.  If you can't write a better name, then can you offer more detail in the comment?  Update of what?  Why do we need this?  What are some assumptions (is null allowable)?