# In the spirit of consistency, is it acceptable to comment everything equally?

Tags: programming-practices, comments

Consistency is something I value (at an OCD perfectionist level to be honest). I can live with not writing *any* comments and focus on producing good, refactored, readable code -- or, if I must comment, I would prefer to decide on a very specific comment pattern and comment in that way throughout the entire code consistently, not just to explain certain complicated parts.

Is commenting everything as described or not at all, but not "somewhere in between" an acceptable coding practice?

Comment: As an aside, after reading 3-4 questions about commenting on this site, I'm left with a divided very non-unanimous opinion on the matter: **To comment or not to comment, that is the (borderline-religious) question**. Comment. Don't comment. No one agrees on the matter. I suppose it's a question you ask your project manager when you start and accept whatever the answer is.

Comment: No, project managers don't get to dictate that.

Comment: @Telastyn - I respectfully disagree. They do , and if in your case they don´t - then they should . Read my answer .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Your answer appears to be based on the premise that "programmers" are bad at programming yet their bosses are good at programming. This may be true in some companies, but it's definitely not true where I work. I'm with Telastyn that there are much more important things to worry about than "comment consistency", and that "project managers" don't necessarily have any special authority on the matter.

Comment: @lxrec - You are really far reaching .. I do not know where you got this conclusion that I think programmers are bad at programming . All I pointed out is that comments, if well executed,  are important for continuity. project managers ( why the parenthesis at job descriptions ? ) are responsible for the project and its continuity. programmers are responsible for executing the needs of the project. that is basic hierarchy - weather the programmer likes it or not .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - you have a distorted view of the role project managers have in most organizations.

Comment: @Telastyn . Yes, I might . After all I have not worked in **MOST** organizations, only in a few . and formed just a little few myself. I guess if you yourself have past "most" organizations than I should accept your opinion. after all - I am always for taking advice from the **most** experienced in **most** organizations .  Sorry, I was totally wrong thinking that project managers must manage the project . My bad ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At my first real job I was hired by a couple of OCDers who wanted me to always write code like this:

```
/* comment describing what the next few lines do */
a line of code
a line of code
a line of code

/* comment describing what the next few lines do */
a line of code
a line of code
a line of code
```

etc.

The idea was that it should be possible to gain a relatively good understanding of what the code does by reading through the comments, completely disregarding the actual code.  For this to work there were some additional rules, for example that code comments always had to begin with a verb, etc.

So, I learned to program this way, and I thought it was cool.  Unfortunately, this led to many WTF situations, like the following:

```
function int foo( int x )
{
    /* preconditions */
    assert x > 0;

    /* change state */
    this.x = x;

    /* return same value to enable fluent style */
    return x;
}
```

At jobs that I did after that, people either looked at my coding style and did not say anything in order to avoid insulting me, or, if they felt friendly enough to give me advice, they told me that this style of commenting was *moronic*.

Furthermore, other programmers did not feel obliged at all to follow my style of commenting, so when someone else amended my code, their complete disregard towards my comments was often tantamount to subversion, for example:

```
    /* return same value to enable fluent style */
    notifyTheWorldThatXHasChanged();
    return x;
```

So, in my experience, in most workplaces out there, this style of commenting tends to be frowned upon.

My advice would be to write self-documenting code and follow the "minimal comments" rule, which means only add a comment if it is necessary.  Comments in code should only be needed in exceptional circumstances, and their presence should alert the reader that there is something extraordinary going on.

**When is a comment necessary?** When a reasonably careful reading of the code does not reveal what the code does, or why a certain thing is done in a particular way.

**What should be considered *a reasonably careful* reading of the code?** It is when you focus all of your attention to reading the code, with an honest aim to understand what it does, but you trust that the code actually does what it appears to aim to do, so you are not actually going through the pain of executing the code in your mind, trying to figure out what it *really* does, as if the code has [ulterior motives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulterior_motive).  You should only have to do that when debugging code.

Of course, the trick is to write that elusive self-documenting code which, when you look at it, its aim becomes readily obvious.  I like to believe that what we do is mostly a science, but this particular little bit seems more like an art to me.  An art well worth mastering.

Comment: Practising self documenting code is the key. Explaining the intent of the code out loud to myself and using those words in the method names and variable names really helps me

Answer (score 3):

Acceptable to whom?

If your boss will fire you because you were inconsistent in your comments, it is maybe not acceptable. If your boss fires you because you went OCD with the comments rather than shipping, it is maybe not acceptable.

Consistency in comments is... Okay I guess. Consistency in code is better. Consistency in tests is better. Consistency in process is better. And good comments, good code, good process, and good tests are better than consistently bad stuff.

So the question about if it is *acceptable* or not is rather moot, because nobody much cares about it.

Comment: You sort of wrote what I commented reflectively.

Answer (score -5):

First , as @Telastyn wrote , your question is rather subjective ..
Also , it seems that the problem is not with your boss / company / team / world-standards , but internally yours.

As such, I can only give my two cents ( read : opinion )  on the matter .

This answer was heavily edited after I was educated  ( by the kind users ) on the merits on non-commenting . Never. In any situation . in any language. in any tool .Even if it stands on the way of my instincts as a programmer to predict unpredictable situations. In this case - there are none. Everyone will always understand my code which will always be on top-zen level and maintained by me.

<strike>Commenting is Crucial .</strike> 
Comments are awful. You should NEVER use them . use ZEN .

<strike>I was a programmer in the past .</strike>  Today <strike>I am the Boss .</strike> 
This has given me  <strike>two</strike>  a very different perspectives on the matter .

**As a programmer**, you do not really understand why you always need to comment. seems a waste of time . I mean, I know my own code , right ?
 
<strike>Well - not always . Try going back to some obscure code that you yourself wrote 15 years ago in a language you maybe not use as frequent as you did - and suddenly you wish you were commenting better ...
Today, after a lot of years, I comment every function even before I write the function itself.</strike>

( small **edit** : take a look at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/482/197110) I just found )
. 
**As a Boss** ( or owner of a company ) - commenting is a <strike>high level</strike> not a requirement, for the simple reason that <strike>today, the staff and employees has little , if not none , fidelity to the workplace . they can quit the job on a day´s notice ( or no notice at all ) , or simply get fired for any one reason ,  Or in more extreme cases , something bad could happen ( accident , sudden sickness, even death - its part of life ) and then someone else ( called a `code maintainer`) must fill that persons shoes , meaning to read all the past code and</strike> everyone will ALWAYS  understand it . Then commenting is <strike>the</strike> only <strike>rescue at hand</strike> NOISE .

If you are looking for a world defined standard for commenting, you will probably wont find it  <strike>( although there are language-specific ( like [PHPdoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) ) and even project-specific standards ) .</strike> Because honestly , I was thought it should not exist.

If you are looking for an answer on if to comment or not - I say <strike>Yes</strike> Defiantly no!. Comment as much as noise you can get.

If you are looking for an answer on `what` or `where` to comment - you will have to .<strike>use your common sense and find it yourself.</strike> Just stop commenting - thus constructing some kind of personal standard for your future work. ( this is what I eventually did ).

.. and if you are looking for an answer for your direct question *"all or nothing"* - than IMHO <strike>all  is better then nothing</strike> Nothing is always better, but still - <strike>common sense</strike> not commenting option is your best friend .

Comment: With respect, things like phpdoc, javadoc etc are not about commenting, they are about documenting your public api, not about commenting on the code inside your methods. There is a big difference. Documentation is important for consumers to be able to easily use you libraries (ie msdn). Comments in the code can be made virtually redundant by changing the structure of the code so it is more self documentation. See the 'clean code' movement. IMHO if you are a boss you should be telling your programmers to change how they code so the code is cleaner, not telling them to comment everything.

Comment: @SamHolder first - I gave an example of `phpdoc` only because of it´s de-facto standard status, and not related to it´s purpose. it i still qualifies as code commenting. second do notice I did not made a difference between types of comments - you did that judgment. Third - you are assuming that all coders are as good as yourself. in a real world scenario that is simply not true. commenting code can help the less enabled coders to understand the process of a more enabled one . In a company of 100+ programmers , that is important. I guess those are conclusions that come with experience. ..

Comment: @SamHolder - and BTW - I would like to know how can you really debug code on a green-screen CNC machine or PLC  , in a factory or a plant , without syntax highlighter and without comment blocks....

Comment: I'm stating that code  documentation and comments are very different, and to group them together is wrong. Even if you wrote great clean chide with no comments you may still need extensive documentation. And I stand by my statement that if you are encouraging your devs to comment (not document) the code then you are only adding to the problem. You should instead do code reviews and pair refactoring sessions to clean the code and remove to need for the comments. Otherwise how will any of your guys and girls get any better?

Comment: Comments quickly rot in my experience and bear little relevance to the code they are around. Clean code can't.

Comment: sorry I missed the part of the question stating that the code was used in that environment. Are you suggesting that all code should be commented as a tiny percentage of it might be debugged on a green screen?

Comment: @SamHolder I think you meant to write **badly written and irrelevant ** comments rot quickly...  all what the "anti-comment" movement people are writing is idealistic and adapted to one-person, one-language, one-code, and one very clean office paradigm . not working in all real world scenarios. Like I said - have you ever been to power plant with old 80´s or 90´s computer to work and have you ever seen, or had to debug `binary code` or `g-code` without comments ? I would presume the answer is no. If yes, I am willing to contract you immediately at a cost of your willing.

Comment: Quit micromanaging. Commenting code isn't a high level requirement - quality software is a high level requirement, maintainable code is a high level requirement. Comments are a means to an end, and as a boss, you should get used to letting your experts determine the best way to get there.

Comment: @Telastyn - I think I have made clear in my answer that I did not started as the boss or owner. I started as a simple programmer. anyhow- I understand that you have a thing against code commenting. I really get it .but if you will read my answer - you will see that I just expressed my opinion based on my experience . and the final answer was left for the "common sense" of the OP. So if you want to vote down the fact that I left the answer to own common sense , please do . But again - please stop taking it to a personal level of " you have a distorted view" and "..if you are the boss than .. "

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I do not agree with it, but that alone is not worthy of downvote.

Comment: @Telastyn & @Sam Holder , this discussion of ours becoming rather long, but one thing that I really would like to know in order to understand your coherence adversary to comments  - Do you also think that ( obligatory ) commit comments ( example `.git` ) on version control systemsare also a `"no-no"` ? After all, if we all code perfectly, and we all on the same coding level - we would not need those, right ?

Comment: @obmerk you seem to be convinced that all text Associated with code is 'comments' and serves the same purpose and so can be lumped together. I fundamentally disagree with this.  Documentation comments (javadoc,XMLdoc etc), source code commit comments, and in line comments in the source are all for very different purposes. The first explains the external usage and behavior to consumers. The second held to identify what changes a particular commit makes to the overall code base. Without this how would you go about finding when some feature was added to the code? Check it every version and read

Comment: through it? Those comments are shown in a different tool to the code comments because they have a different use. I believe that by suggesting they are the same and therefore I obviously would want to use those if I am against in line comments you are being deliberately argumentative as this is a patently ridiculous argument.

Comment: All I am suggesting is that in line comments are a crutch that can be removed by better structure in your code. And in my experience people can learn to do this if directed and forced to think about things. Also with in line comments you force the developers to update the comments when they are changing the code, which increases the amount of work. and if they forget then all if a sudden the code and the comments are out of sync and it becomes difficult to reason effectively about what the intent should be. Are the comments what was intended and the code is wrong? Or vice versa?

Comment: A quick search for g-code on stack overflow on my phone results in 26 questions. If you believe that advising people to user comments because this language requires them due to it's limitations (which it may well do) then I think you are being deliberately disingenuous. No where in your answer did you qualify it by saying something like 'in some languages the structures necessary to avoid comments are not available and so continuing to follow the existing commenting patterns would be vital', you just flat out stated that you think all code should be heavily commented.

Comment: And this didn't even answer the question, it just says all code should be commented, regardless of existing style

Comment: @SamHolder - Strange, my [Search for g-code](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=g-code) resulted in 35,977 but that is out of the point, as so are all those comments / discussion ( and we are not on a dscussion board ) soo... You win ( yeyy!! ) . I bend to say that comments are always awful and never useful . I will change my answer now .

Comment: I didn't search, I just looked for questions tagged g-code, but I was on my phone so results might have been trimmed. Honestly I think you have had a rather childish response to having your opinion challenged, but whatever.